# Do we have a genAI content policy? Should we have one?

Tags: discussion, generative-ai

Contrary to some sites and groups of people being quite openly hostile to the general use of generative AI to ask and answer questions, I have found philosophy SE refreshingly silent on that topic. I have been wondering if we can get some sort of site-wide policy out into the clear, especially given that we, as philosophers, I would hope, are more poised than some others to offer an analysis for why one should or should not regard AI as a legitimate way of accessing and generating information or knowledge.

Personally, I happen to be in the extreme pro-AI-leaning camp. I have never had any issue with someone posting content fully generated by an AI as a response to an answer, or as a question, without even attributing or acknowledging it as such. It never occurred to me that that would bother me, at all. Furthermore, I would like to see more of it, because I think a lot of modern AIs are extremely smart, knowledgeable, and good at writing, so we would see a huge uptick in quality content if more and more content was written with the aid of AI, if not written completely by AI. I recognize this puts me in something of a countercultural position compared to the Stack Exchange norm, apparently.

Anyway, I am considering being a little more liberal in my use of AI on the site, and a little less guarded. But I was curious if community members think we should have any rules on that; which ones; and why.

Answer (score 2):

The general policy can, like all general policies, be found on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393679/is-uncited-llm-usage-considered-a-coc-violation-under-the-inauthentic-usage-poli/393682#393682).

The essence of it is as follows:

> TL;DR: Yes, the current Inauthentic Usage policy prohibits posting AI-generated content without appropriate attribution.

The same can be found in our [help center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/ai-policy) that has a whole article on the matter.

If you have any suggestions for more specific rules, feel free to go forward with that.